# Combine string in DF Python

Tags: python, pandas

Please,

Can you help me about this code?

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
   ID    values
0   1        A
1   2        B
2   1        A
3   4        C
```

I want this DF

```
  ID    values
    0   1        A,A
    1   2        B
    3   4        C
```

Or:

```
  ID    values
    0   1        2xA
    1   2        B
    3   4        C
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['values'].agg(','.join)`

Comment: No you don't want that. If it is to learn how to build a list of a string inside dataframe cells, it can be acceptable. In any *real* use case it is terrible because you a explicitely building a non vectorizable element.

Comment: Agreed with @SergeBallesta , try not to do that